# How to avoid creating nohup.out and in this case where the output will be generated?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I am running a matlab script which taking input arguments and output folder is assigned in the function. 
When I am running nohup like this
nohup ./matlabscript.h &
then it generates a nohup.out file which is really huge. How do I avoid creating that file?
The output folder is assigned, so I am not sure whether an output file needs to be assigned?
Thank you

Comment: IIRC `nohup` notices whether stdout is connected to a terminal and only in that case create the `nohup.out`. If you explicitly redirect using `nohup ./script > /dev/null` you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @filmor. Is it going to take memory in /dev/null?

Comment: `/dev/null` is a pseudo-device, writing to it is a no-op (taking neither memory nor time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [filmor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542190/filmor) commented, you could [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) *stdout* to some file.

```
nohup ./script > script.out &
```

or even redirect both *stdout* and *stderr* to the same file

```
nohup ./script > script.out 2>&1 &
```

or to a different one

```
nohup ./script > script.out 2> script.err &
```

To discard an output, redirect it to `/dev/null`. The data is basically destructed, so no memory is used. See [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html). If you want to discard both outputs use:

```
nohup ./script > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

[nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html) notices when both outputs are redirected, thus doesn't create the `nohup.out` file (provided none of the two outputs is a terminal, see [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)).

I would also recommend considering using [batch(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?batch%201) e.g. with a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

```
batch << EOJ
  ./script > script.out 2>&1
EOJ
```

Read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).